# Error when __setattr__ for List

Tags: python

I am implementing all of the predefined function for a class, and I am stuck when i implement my`__setattr__()` for updating a list

```
class testop:
    def __init__(self):
        self.li=[x*2 for x in list(range(5))]
    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.li[index]
    def __setattr__(self,attr,value):
        self.__dict__[attr]+=value #self.__dict__[attr].append(value)

if __name__=='__main__':
    testop().li=3
```

Error:

```
line 10, in <module>
    testop().li=30
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/testop.py", line 3, in __init__
    self.li=[x*2 for x in list(range(5))]
  File "C:/Users/Desktop/testop.py", line 7, in __setattr__
    self.__dict__[attr]+=value
KeyError: 'li'
```

for normal variables other than list it does work fine, can anyone say what i am missing?

> Thanks for the answers and i am getting it clear why
>   `self.__dict__[attr]` fail to find the key, Hmmmmmm but the normal
>   variables it does work fine even when not adding it before hand to the
>   `dict`?

Comment: When you say `+=`, the key should already exist. If you're doing this for the first time, the key will not be there so it errors out.

Comment: Wasn't the `li` got initialized in the __init__?

Comment: well you tried to but `self.li = ...` calls `__setattr__` which tried to increment the already existing attribute.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that when `__init__` is called, `li` doesn't exist yet.

Basically, what's happening is that as part of `__init__` you call `__setattr__` to set `li`. But, `li` doesn't exist yet, so you get a keyerror.

What you need to do is check if the attribute exists before you try to add to it.

```
class testop:
    def __init__(self):
        self.li = [x * 2 for x in list(range(5))]

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.li[index]

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        if attr in self.__dict__:
            self.__dict__[attr] += value
        else:
            pass  # Either create it or throw an exception, whatever you want to do.


if __name__ == '__main__':
    testop().li = 3
```

Comment: So, it isn't safe to set variable in `init` when we have `setattr` as well?

Comment: @Explorer_N I mean, there are plenty of implementations of `setattr` where it would be okay (like the one in my answer). This one in particular one just tries to access and modify a variable without checking if it exists first.

Answer (score 1):

The problem there is, that the `__init__` function does `self.li = something` which calls `__setattr__`. and since there is no `li` defined at the time, it fails, so in the `__init__` function you should also assign using `__dict__`, like this:

```
self.__dict__['li']=[x*2 for x in list(range(5))]
```

Comment: you mean `self.__dict__['li'] = ...`?

Comment: self.__dict__['li']=[x*2 for x in list(range(5))], this makes sense

Comment: This will work as well, the issue is that you'll have to do it for every attribute instead of just fixing your `setattr`.